# installing python bcrypt module on windows command

Tags: python, bcrypt

when I use pip install bcrypt on windows command, it raises this error:

```
command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that bcrypt doesn't install on Windows Vista or 7, 32 or 64 bit using pip with Python 2.7.  A work around is to download a wheel file with bcrypt and to install that.  For instance, download the appropriate wheel file from here:
https://bitbucket.org/alexandrul/py-bcrypt/downloads .  There may be other repositories; this was just the first one I stumbled across.
After downloading, type:

```
pip install wheel
pip install py_bcrypt.whl
```

where py_bcrypt.whl is the name of the wheel file you downloaded for your particular Windows version.

Comment: When I tried this, I got "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement py-bcrypt-0.4-cp27-none-win32.whl"

Comment: Wheel files are now offcially available [here](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/#files)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to using pre-built wheels is to enable your local environment to build a wheel for you. The advantage is, that you don't need to take manual actions (such as downloading some files from the Internet) nor to pin the wheel's version and target architecture. Instead, you take full advantage of the `pip install` automation.

In the particular case of `bcrypt` installing [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://%20https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) should solve the problem.